# Why won't my do while loop stop break?

Tags: c, do-while, digits, cs50

I am trying to make a do-while loop. I am trying to get the user input as long as the user's input's length of the digit is less than 13 digits long or greater than 16 digits long.

Example:
1234 (4 digits) would run the do while loop again,
123493919295919(14 digits) would stop the loop.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    int nDigits;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Please enter your credit card number:\n");
        nDigits = floor(log10(abs(n))) + 1;
    }
    while (nDigits < 13 || nDigits > 16);
}
```

Comment: `int`s probably can't even hold 14 digits on your setup.

Comment: A credit card number is usually a string, not an int. Imagine that your credit card numbers starts with any zero and you're doomed.

Comment: Don't use `get_int()`. Write your own function. There is nothing you can do to fix your program as long as you are using this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `int` in your system? Is it 4 bytes (32 bits)?

`nDigits` for type `int`, that has 32 bits, will be always less than 11 (I mean that `INT_MAX` which is equal to `2147483647` gives just `10`), so condition is TRUE (because `(nDigits < 13 || nDigits > 16)` gives `true OR false`, that is `true`).

So consider changing type for data representation.

Options:

1. `char[17]` to store strings up to 16 characters (inside string you can check that all characters are digits, see [isdigit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit))
2. `uint64_t` form `<stdint.h>` (there seems to be no negative card numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You should take the credit card number as a string, not an int.

The cs50 Reference Documentation is pretty clear on that:

> `get_int()` reads a line of text from standard input and returns it as
>   an int in the range of [-2^31 + 1, 2^31 - 2], if possible; if text
>   does not represent such an int, user is prompted to retry. Leading and
>   trailing whitespace is ignored. For simplicity, overflow is not
>   detected. If line can’t be read, returns INT_MAX.

As stated by @VolAnd, this terminates in a **signed** int32 which has always less than 11 digits and could even be negative...

Answer (score 0):

I changed the ints to longs and it works. That is what cs50 wants us to use. Thanks for the help to everyone!